# PHP on IIS or Apache ( advantages and disadvantages)

Tags: php, apache, iis, comparison

What are the advantages and disadvantages of running php on IIS?

or

What are the advantages and disadvantages of running php on Apache?

Comment: I'm voting to close as subjective and argumentative, this is too broad to be answered well. There are however some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515/php-on-iis

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197953/apache-vs-iis-php-performance-comparison

Comment: A good link on the topic from that question: http://www.bestcodingpractices.com/php_on_iis_compared_to_php_on_apache-15511.html

Comment: I believe this is not a programming related question, and is about servers. Server performance, maintenance, features. I vote for transferring this question on serverfault. Let the gurus there judge whether it can or can't be answered objectively.

Comment: This question is quite broad, it fits into a lot of categories (Programming, Server Side, Software) .. Im not sure where it belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible duplication of: [apache-vs-iis-php-performance-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197953/apache-vs-iis-php-performance-comparison)

Comment: Not everything comes down to performance. More sides should be considered: Cost of implementation, features, security, and performance.

Comment: @AlexanderMP: absolutely correct, sorry for the assumption... since asking between a free product and a commercial one i naturally thought that performance was the field of interest in this case

Comment: :) having a free licence doesn't mean that it's cheaper in implementation and maintenance. Usually, web hosts offer the same price for Linux hosting and Windows hosting, which does mean that the costs are pretty much the same. I think this is indeed a very broad question to have a simple answer. Very thorough analysis should be performed in order to answer this correctly, and it would be more appropriate for sites like ServerFault, since it's 2 servers which are being judged.

Comment: @Srinivas Tamada how can this possibly be marked as answer when it refers to a resource that is 2 years old and woefully out of date.

Answer (score 1):

There's so many resources available on the internet to help you sum up the comparison:

- http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/07/iis-vs-apache.aspx
- http://www.apache-php-mysql.com/apache/apache-vs-iss.php
- http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3074841/IIS-vs-Apache-Looking-Beyond-the-Rhetoric.htm
- http://www.diffen.com/difference/Apache_vs_IIS
- http://www.webhostingfan.com/2009/07/apache-vs-iis-web-server/
- http://www.search-this.com/2007/06/27/microsoft-iis-vs-apache-who-serves-more/
- Some images to help summarize there net presence

  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGSa8.gif
  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmxKh.gif
- Some Slides:

  - http://www.slideshare.net/itsec/apache-vs-iis-myths

this should be enough information to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I know about problems when uploading files via php to a windows server.
When the temp directory is not properly set, the permission of the uploaded files will be wrong too.

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php somewhere in the comments.

Comment: You just have to give the permissions to the Application Pool, and then it can access the temp directory, and this should be comment

Answer (score -3):

Apache better, many php application need to use apache mod.
for example: url_rewrite

Comment: this answer is purely an opinion with no basis to back it up. it is not helping the asker get closer to the answer he is looking for